# The server is unwilling to process request

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-3.0

I am trying use powershell to add OU called Calder under an OU called Branches but I keep getting the error `New-ADOrganizationalUnit : The server is unwilling to process the request.`, Also I am running powershell as a admin

Here is what I put in powershell

```
New-ADOrganizationalUnit "Calder" -Path "OU=Branches, DC=company.epl, DC=local
```

Here is the full error

> New-ADOrganizationalUnit : The server is unwilling to process the
>   request At line:1 char:1
>   + New-ADOrganizationalUnit "Calder" -Path "OU=Branches, DC=company.epl …
>   +  + CategoryInfo  :NotSpecified: (OU=Calder, OU+Br...y.epl, DC=local:Strin  g) [New-ADOrganizationalUnit] :
>   ActiveDirectoryServer:O,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADOrganizationalUnit

Comment: did you add closing double quotes and remove the spaces in your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've generally seen this error when I've got my fully qualified DN mistyped. If that is the case, using a search to grab the intended OU object helps.

```
PS> $MYOU = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -filter 'Name -like "Branches"'
PS> $MYOU.DistinguishedName
OU=Branches,dc=MyCompany,dc=ccTLD
PS> New-ADOrganizationalUnit "Calder" -Path $MYOU.DistinguishedName


PS> Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -filter 'Name -like "Calder"'


City                     :
Country                  :
DistinguishedName        : OU=Calder,OU=Branches,dc=MyCompany,dc=ccTLD
LinkedGroupPolicyObjects : {}
ManagedBy                :
Name                     : Calder
ObjectClass              : organizationalUnit
ObjectGUID               : 559c4242-505a-c165-15d5-562b5fb99103
PostalCode               :
State                    :
StreetAddress            :
```

If it's not just an incorrect OU path, try appending `-Verbose` to the command and see if there's a better indication of what exactly went awry.