# Adding users via powershell script gives error

Tags: powershell

I am trying to ad users from a csv file to an OU with a powershell script but getting some error?

I'll post the line that I am using for adding the users. And I have checked that the retrieval path for the csv file is correct..

```
New-ADUser -SamAccountName $login -Name $namn -GivenName $Fname -Surname $Enamn -Department $user.Department -Division $user.Division -Title $user.role -Description $user.Extension -Office $user.Office -UserPrincipalName $login"@hqad.local" -path "OU=Carb_users,DC=HQAD,DC=Local" -EmailAddress $mail -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "Syp9393" -Force) -Enable $True
```

Error output:

```
New-ADUser : The server is unwilling to process the request
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Userscript.ps1:37 char:1
+ New-ADUser -SamAccountName $login -Name $namn -GivenName $Fname -Surn ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=Carl Malm,OU...C=HQAD,DC=Local:String) [New-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
```

Happy for any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The server is unwilling to process request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52508703/the-server-is-unwilling-to-process-request)

Comment: Sadly it does not :/

Comment: For one thing, `$login"@hqad.local"` --> `"$login@hqad.local"` As for the rest of the parameters, there is no way for us to check since you do not show any of the csv file. As aside, I want to suggest using [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) on cmdlets that have lots of parameters instead of creating a very long single line of code. That will make mistakes easier to spot.