# Add-ADGroupMember : The server is unwilling to process the request

Tags: powershell

When I executed the command

```
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group.DistinguishedName -Members $User.DistinguishedName -Server "DC001:3268"
```

I get below error

```
Add-ADGroupMember : The server is unwilling to process the request
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group.DistinguishedName -Members $User.D ..
```

Comment: Global Catalogs (`:3268`) are _read-only_ partitions. Target the regular LDAP interface (port 389 or 636) if you want to _write_ to the directory

Comment: As you can read here [The server is unwilling to process request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52508970/1701026) the ` DistinguishedName` is probably misspelled. So what is in your `$Group.DistinguishedName` or `$User.DistinguishedName` (please, add sample values to the question). Are there any special characters (that can't be round tripped) in there?

Comment: @iRon You can format the DN all you want, GC still won't process modifications :-)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen,

         Tried both 389 and 636 port
-----------------------------
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group.DistinguishedName -Members $User.DistinguishedName -Server "DC001:389"
Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity:'CN=UserName,OU=UK,OU=India,OU=Sites,DC=EUROPE,DC=COMPANY,DC=LOCAL' under: 
'DC=americas,DC=COMPANY,DC=LOCAL'.       
                                   
----------------
 Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group.DistinguishedName -Members $User.DistinguishedName -Server "DC001:636"
Add-ADGroupMember : Server instance not found on the given port.

Comment: I think you already asked this on another occasion, you should not be pointing to a Global Catalog, the cmdlet will only work pointing to a writable DC on LDAP / LDAPS ports.